# Preserving labels in latent space clustering

Tags: clustering

I generated a latent space from a VAE model for my dataset which consists of images depicting different font styles.  The objective is to reduce the dimensionality of this latent space in order to visualize the clustering of the font styles. However, I'm not sure which font type corresponds to which row in this latent space. Does anyone know how to preserve labels while performing clustering? Here is the method being called when generating the latent space, which is a module I borrowed from [here](https://github.com/AI-Guru/ngdlm/blob/master/ngdlm/models/vae.py).

```
def predict_embed_samples_into_latent(self, x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None):

    return self.encoder.predict(x, batch_size, verbose, steps)[2]
```